# What does Twitter API favourites_count indicate?

Tags: twitter

Quick question, I'm having trouble finding this info on the Twitter dev centre.

On the object for a tweet, in the user section there is 'favourites_count', what exactly does this imply? Is that how many tweets they themsevles have favourited? or is it perhaps how many of their tweets have been favourited? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 7):

It's the number of tweets that given user has marked as favorite.

I check'd this with an [API call with my own screen name](http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=daknok).

Comment: If you want to know how many tweets for a particular user were favorited, you can scan that user's timeline and check the status object's `favorited` property.

Answer (score 0):

The number of Tweets this user has liked in the account’s lifetime. British spelling used in the field name for historical reasons.